# Executing jar file with file name as argument

Tags: java, contextmenu, desktop-application, right-click

I have created a JAVA application to get the IMDB ratings of movies. The application takes one command line argument (name of the movie) and displays the rating of the same. I have added the application to the right-click context menu. so, now when I right click I need the file name (without extension) to be passed as a command line argument. How can I do this?

I tried adding `%1` as placeholder in the registry but it doesn't seem to work. The application works from the command line with an argument.

Can someone help me?

**COMMAND LINE:**

```
java -jar C:\NetBeansProjects\APPLICATION\dist\APPLICATION.jar daredevil
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**RIGHT CLICK MENU** 
[image]

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.IMDB.IMDBFetch(IMDB.java:67)
    at application.IMDB.URLParse(IMDB.java:54)
    at application.IMDB$4.run(IMDB.java:387)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**REGISTRY ENTRY**

```
java -jar "C:\NetBeansProjects\APPLICATION\dist\APPLICATION.jar" "%1"
```

Comment: Well what do you receive in your java program? What's causing the NPE?

Comment: The name of the movie is received as a command line argument. 
Whn I right click on a file, the name of the file is suppossed to be received but that is not being received I guess, which causes the NPE.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Modify your program to dump the value of the argument you actually receive, to ensure the issue is really in passing the argument. What would passing a wrong argument cause a NPE?

Answer (score 0):

> put your `jar` file in your `jre/lib/ext` folder then compile your program without `-jar` Option.

Everything said about the `classpath` is true, but this is a consistent and sensible place for it to live.

you can find out your `jre` folder by looking at the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable on Windows.